# Execute "tar -cf" command from "send to" batch file to .tar.gz a file quickly

Tags: command-line, batch, tar

I installed the [GNU tar for windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gtar.htm) to speed up tar-ing files so I don't have to mess around opening 7zip twice to tar then gzip a file.

To speed up the process even more, I tried to write a send-to batch file that looks like this:

```
tar -cf %1.tar.gz %1
```

The command works fine in the terminal (when I open it in my working dir) and would look something like:

```
tar -cf myfile.tar.gz myfile.txt
```

However when I run the send-to batch file the input ends up being:

```
tar -cf C:\path\to\myfile.txt.tar.gz C:\path\to\myfile.txt
```

I get this error from tar:

```
C:\path\to\my>tar -cf C:\path\to\my\myfile.txt.tar.gz C:\path\to\my\myfile.txt
tar: Cannot open C:\path\to\my\myfile.txt.tar.gz: Function not implemented
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

I'm not really sure what's wrong here but I'm certain it's not a problem with tar but rather some confusion with paths and file names.

I was wondering if there's a nice and simple way to do this with a batch script (maybe get JUST the file name as an argument rather than the full path) or will I need to do something more elaborate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that tar does not accept a full path to the archive being created. You should modify your batch file to cd to the desired folder first, e.g.

```
cd "%~dp1"
```

and then use

```
tar -cf "%~n1.tar.gz" "%~nx1"
```

Quotes are used here to accommodate for space-containing names.

Comment: Perfect! I didn't know about those argument modifiers, thanks!